# Standard or child visitor visa for the UK

Tags: uk

My wife and I have a standard visitor visa. I want to apply for a visa for my children, age 8 and 3. What visa category should I select, and how to fill employment and income in case of child applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to apply for Standard Visitor Visas for them too. The employment and income sections aren't valid for children but you will need to show that you can support them financially.

[If you're under 18](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/if-youre-under-18)

> You can apply for a standard visitor visa if you’re under 18 and:
>
> - you’ve made suitable arrangements for your travel and stay in the UK
> - you have consent from your parent or guardian to travel to the UK
> - you’re able to pay for your return or onward journey
> - you have enough money to support yourself without working or getting help from public funds, or you have family and friends that can support you
>
> When travelling to the UK with an adult (someone over the age of 18), you’ll need to identify them in your visa application.
>
> If the person you’re travelling with isn’t your parent, you’ll need to provide specific information about them in your application.
>
> Their name will appear on your visa, and you’ll be refused entry to the UK if you arrive in the UK without them.
>
> You can identify up to 2 adults in your visa application, and your visa will only be valid if you travel with at least one of them.
>
> The adult can apply for a visa at the same time, but you must each complete separate applications.